# React Native: dynamic styles class variable

Tags: react-native

I am facing problems to dynamically pass styles variable to a  field. Here is my code:

```
for(let i=-2;i<4;++i) {
    var classname = (i==0) ? 'styles.selected' : '';
    dates.push(
    <Text style={classname}>{Moment(currentDate).format('ddd')}{"\n"}{Moment(currentDate).format('DD')}</Text>
    );
}
```

The idea is simple. I want the first text field to be of the class styles.selected, all other text field don't have any class. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in React Native styles are objects, not strings so you have to do like below

```
for(let i=-2;i<4;++i) {
    var classname = (i==0) ? styles.selected : {};
    dates.push(
    <Text style={classname}>{Moment(currentDate).format('ddd')}{"\n"}{Moment(currentDate).format('DD')}</Text>
    );
}
```

You can either use an empty object or null for the else part.